# What are the take-off parameters for the B-25 Mitchell?

Tags: aircraft-performance, takeoff, b-25-mitchell

What is the take-off distance and speed in standard atmosphere (59°F, 29.92 inHg, 0% humidity) for the B-25 Mitchell with max, minimum, or average payload?

Answer (score 4):

[You can find the full POH here](http://www.avialogs.com/viewer/avialogs-documentviewer.php?id=16150), no wind, standard atmosphere, at gross weight you are looking at 3800 ft. of ground roll and 4700 ft to clear a 50 foot obstacle. Take a look at the charts for the other weights as well as other runway surface types.

[image]

([source](http://www.avialogs.com/viewer/avialogs-documentviewer.php?id=16150))